# concat two different list values of different size from two columns in pandas into one list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have different list values in pandas such as

```
         A                   B
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]       [9,10,11] 
  [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]       [12,34,12]
```

I want to combine two list values into one list and store them in another column like

```
  A                        B             C    
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]       [9,10,11]       [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]       [12,34,12]      [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,34,12]
```

Comment: Do you have an issue with what you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

simple way to do it is:

```
df["C"]=df["A"]+df["B"]
```

Comment: I tried with this but getting error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (3,)

Comment: i guess your column values type  is `np.array` not ` list` try this after importing `numpy`
`df["C"]=df.apply(lambda x:np.concatenate((x["A"],x["B"])),axis=1)`

Comment: Still It is not working

Comment: what error do you get and can you provide a sample of your data ?